# Unable to resolve path to module '@nivo/pie'

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, nivo-react

I'm trying to use [Nivo Pie Chart](https://nivo.rocks/pie/), it's giving me this error on import:

> Unable to resolve path to module '@nivo/pie'

```
import { ResponsivePie } from '@nivo/pie';
```

Trying to figure out what needs to be installed, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install package before using it. Please try running

```
yarn add @nivo/pie
```

or

```
npm install @nivo/pie --save
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to install first `yarn add @nivo/core`, from the documentation:

In order to use **nivo**, you have to install the `@nivo/core` package and then choose some of the scoped `@nivo` packages according to the charts you wish to use:
https://github.com/plouc/nivo#installation